# Github contributions graph

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, github, svg

There is a wonderful contributions chart that github.com came with.

[image]

Does anybody know if they use some kind of library or gem?

If it is open source, I would like to use it my project as well. It looks great!

Comment: I'm sure they would tell you if you ask them.

Comment: How am I supposed to ask? Do they have some kind of Q&A? I couldn't find.

Comment: https://github.com/support

Comment: See also https://github.com/k4rthik/git-cal, that I reference in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15988356/6309

Comment: Check out Cal-heatmap

Comment: if you use react, here's a react component for it: http://patientslikeme.github.io/react-calendar-heatmap/

Comment: this might be what you're looking for:  https://github.com/2016rshah/githubchart-api which has the gem and you can display the chart pointing to your own repo within an img tag without installing anything

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Not exactly the same style, but I think it's done using the [calendar example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/calendar.html) of D3.js.

If you do a "View Source" on GitHub's page, you'll see that they're using D3 for rendering their calendar.

A similar look is achieved by [js-chart-widgets](https://github.com/loule/js-chart-widgets/).

Comment: I just put together a d3.js plugin for that : https://github.com/kamisama/cal-heatmap. Still in beta and some quirks in Firefox, but it has some nice features

Comment: @Kamisama Thanks.Your plugin will save me countless hours.

Comment: @Kamisama brilliant work and excellent documentation! Just as a side note, would like to add, that would be awesome if you could add functionality that picks the start date (let's say 15th of September 2016) and calendar is populated from that day till 15 of September 2017). So you would have ranges 15 - 31 in first block, and 1 - 14 in the last block (all of this assumes 1 year date range and month/day as domain/subdomain)

Answer (score 2):

The Github Contributions calendar is using D3. If you inspect your network traffic you'll see the request for the JS and you can look through the source yourself.

EDIT: I've removed the source link as the CDN url is likely to change over time. It should still be locatable if you take a look with your web inspector.

Comment: Broken URL - maybe update it to something that will not break based on CDN changes?