# How can I add "current streak" of contributions from github to my blog?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, html-parsing

I have a personal blog I built using rails. I want to add a section to my site that displays my current streak of github contributions. What would be the best way about doing this?

edit: for clarification, here is what I want:

[image]

just the number of days is all that is necessary for me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Considering the [GitHub API for Users](http://developer.github.com/v3/users/) doesn't yet expose that particular information (number of days for current stream of contributions), you might have to:

- scrape it (extract it by reading the user's GitHub page)
  As [klamping](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150552/klamping) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18008037/6309) (upvoted), the url to scrap would be:
  <del>`https://github.com/users/<username>/contributions_calendar_data`</del>
  **`https://github.com/users/<username>/contributions`**
  (for public repos only, though)

  [SherlockStd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5567941/sherlockstd) has an [updated (May 2017) parsing code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44007340/6309) below:

  ```
  https://github-stats.com/api/user/streak/current/:username
  ```
- try projects which are using `https://github.com/users/<username>/contributions`<del>`_calendar_data`</del> (as listed in [Marques Johansson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156674/marques-johansson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24802507/6309), upvoted)

  - [**IonicaBizau/git-stats**](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats):

[image: git-stats]

- [akerl/githubchart](https://github.com/akerl/githubchart) (Github contribution SVG generator)
- [akerl/githubstats](https://github.com/akerl/githubstats) (Github contribution statistics)

[image: https://github.com/akerl/githubchart]

- build that graph yourself: see the [**GitHub project git-cal**](https://github.com/k4rthik/git-cal)

[image: https://raw.github.com/k4rthik/git-cal/master/screenshots/img1.png]

> `git-cal` is a simple script to view commits calendar (similar to GitHub contributions calendar) on command line.
>   Each block in the graph corresponds to a day and is shaded with one of the 5 possible colors, each representing relative number of commits on that day.

- or establish a service that will report, each day, any new commit for that given day to a Google Calendar (using the Google Calendar API through a project like [**nf/streak**](https://github.com/nf/streak)).
  You can then read that information and report it in your blog.

[image: Google Calendar streak]

---

You can find various example of scraping that information:

- [`github_team_calendar.py`](https://github.com/bigsnarfdude/github_team_calendars/blob/master/github_team_calendar.py)
- [`weekend-commits.js`](https://gist.github.com/remy/4654404)

As in:

```
$.getJSON('https://github.com/users/' + location.pathname.replace(/\//g, '') + '/contributions_calendar_data', weekendWork);
```

- [`leaderboard.rb`](https://gist.github.com/hecticjeff/4518181):

Like:

```
leaderboard = members.map do |u|
  user_stats = get("https://github.com/users/#{u}/contributions_calendar_data")
  total = user_stats.map { |s| s[1] }.reduce(&:+)
  [u, total]
end
```

- ... (you get the idea)

Comment: Obsolete, look at [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978845/how-can-i-add-current-streak-of-contributions-from-github-to-my-blog/44007340#44007340)

Answer (score 18):

The URL for the plain JSON data **was**:
https://github.com/users/[username]/contributions_calendar_data
[Edit: Looks like this URL no longer works)

There is a URL which generates the SVG, which other answers have indicated. That is here:
https://github.com/users/[username]/contributions

Simply replace [username] with your github username in the URL and you should be able to see the chart. See other answers for more in-depth explanations

Comment: the data that comes is just for public repos.

Comment: Is this obsolete now?

Comment: @IonicăBizău looks like it. One possible alternative is accessing their data via [the Users api](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-performed-by-a-user), although that include events like watching stuff.

Comment: Obsolete, look at [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978845/how-can-i-add-current-streak-of-contributions-from-github-to-my-blog/44007340#44007340)

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that matches the visual appearance of GitHub's chart, check out these projects which use `https://github.com/users/<username>/contributions_calendar_data` but also apply other factors based on Github's logic.

- https://github.com/akerl/githubchart
- https://github.com/akerl/githubstats

Comment: +1. nice find. I have included those projects in my answer above for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

[Project deprecated and unavalaible for now, will be back online soon.]

Since the URL `https://github.com/users/<username>/contributions_calendar_data` don't work anymore, you have to parse the SVG from `https://github.com/users/<username>/contributions`.

Unfortunately, Github loves security and CORS is disabled on their server.

To solve this issue, I've setup an API for me and everyone who needs it, just `GET https://github-stats.com/api/user/streak/current/{username}` (CORS allowed), and you'll get and answer like:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "currentStreak": 3
}
```

https://github-stats.com will soon implement more stats endpoints :)

Please ask for new endpoint at https://github.com/SherloxFR/github-stats.com/issues, it will be a pleasure to find a way to implement them !

Comment: Nicely done. +1. I have included a link to your post in my answer, for more visibility.

Comment: But it's not working actually because of CORS so I'm deploying a server for this I'll post the URL tonight

Comment: CORS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)... figures! GitHub is security-minded.

Comment: I have edited the answer and included your github-stats endpoint.

Comment: @VonC sorry about that but I updated the endpoint, please update your answer.