# Github contributions for self created repos

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I created a repo on Github and made some commits from the Github windows app, I checked that my email is in sync with my account.

In the "Repositories contributed to" tab I can only see third party repos but not ones created by me...

Does Github not count repos self created as "Contributions"? If they do, how can I show my commits in the "Repositories contributed" to tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Github not count repos self created as "Contributions"?

It does, but not in the list of "repositories contributed to".
That list is only for the repos your forked, made a PR (Pull Request) which was accepted and merged in the original repo.

Your own commits are counted in the [contributions graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15988356/6309) only if (see [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile)) *all* the conditions are met:

> - The commits were made within the past year.
> - The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub account.
> - The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
> - The commits were made in the default branch of the repository.

Comment: Iv seen others who have their own repo showing in that box, is there some trick to get it showing?

Comment: @condo1234 I don't see any of mines in that list (https://github.com/VonC, list "Repositories contributed to")

Comment: @condo1234 do you have any repo url showing "others" with their own repos in that contrib box?